# How to make object transparent on "texture" view mode

Tags: materials, 3d-view, transparency, shaders

I have managed to make an object transparent on solid viewmode, but It is fully opaque when "texture" viewmode is selected.

[image]

The reason I need it transparent for textured view is that I'm editing the object to match a picture projected on a plane behind it. Help!

Comment: Right now I can work around this issue by hiding and revealing the object  repeatedly really fast and get a similar effect...

Comment: If you're rendering in Cycles skip this.  The gif sweeps through a bit fast but to catch it but you don't appear to be selecting "Material" view mode.  Try that and render in OpenGL, see if that gets the results you're after.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in Material viewport shading, which isn't all that different from Texture.

Set the shading to Material and add a material with the following node setup to your object.

[image]

On the Properties Editor make the following changes.

[image: Properties Editor]

Now change the color of the RGB node to your liking.

[image: Result]

If it's imperative that you use Texture shading, the following method should suit your needs just fine (it also works in Material shading):

[image: Alternative]